# Why are USB power and ground connected at the same time?

Tags: usb, connector

Building off [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/185052/why-are-the-contacts-for-the-data-lines-in-usb-a-and-b-plugs-shorter-than-the-co), why are the USB power and ground lines connected at the same time?  Wouldn't it be better to connect ground first, then power, the way [Serial ATA power cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA) does?

Comment: The metal shield connects before the pins, and it is usually connected to GND.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SATA drives typically have higher current concerns than usb does. Power hungry motors in hard drives can lead to large inrush currents, causing draining and spiking on the voltage rail.

> Drive power connector pins 3, 7, and 13 are longer than the others, so they make contact next. The drive uses them to charge its internal bypass capacitors through current-limiting resistances. Finally, the remaining power pins make contact, bypassing the resistances and providing a low-impedance source of each voltage. This two-step mating process avoids glitches to other loads and possible arcing or erosion of the SATA power connector contacts.

Usb on the other hand, has lower current sourcing (by standards limited to 500 mA), and is hampered by backwards compatibility constraints. The plug was designed way before USB became a common power source.

Answer (score -1):

Although the pins of a USB device connect at (about) the same time, the USB upstream device *does not apply power* to the attached device until it has been sensed on the D+ and D- lines (which also indicate what speed it can run at). A USB device will have pull-**downs** to indicate its presence.

Devices that have independent power do not physically connect to the USB power pin.

Once the device has been sensed (which will take a few milliseconds), the USB upstream device will turn on the power switch and then start the enumeration sequence.

So, in effect, the USB power pin and ground pin are attached at different times in terms of power appearing at the USB device being inserted.

**Edit**
The pull-ups are at the other end which does have power.

No power is applied to a USB port until a device is actually plugged in under normal circumstances.

SATA cables have a proper [Hot Swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_swapping) pin arrangement  so power can be available at all times.

Comment: How does the pull-up sensing work when there is no power rail to pull up to?

Comment: 'USB upstream device does not apply power' like limiting devices to requested power only, this happens maybe never. You can test it by cutting a cable and measuring VUSB and GND while the data pins are floating.

Comment: This is incorrect. By spec, the host (or hub) may or may not have a power switch; however, VBUS must still be provided somehow. With no switch on the host it is simply wired to the connector.